# partial template specialization for template pointer to function

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, partial-specialization

Consider the following abstract `Subscription` class:

```
template <typename TMessage>
class Subscription {
public:
    virtual ~Subscription() {}
    virtual bool handle(const TMessage &) = 0;
};
```

In some cases, it could be convenient if one class alone could implement this abstract class **several times** - even for the same `TMessage` - **and** not force inheritance.

To achieve this I am using a template pointer to function in the following way:

```
template <typename TMessage, typename TCaller, bool(TCaller::*TMethod)(const TMessage &)>
class Invoker : public Subscription<TMessage> {
public:
    Invoker(TCaller *caller) :
        m_caller(*caller) {
    }

    virtual bool handle(const TMessage &message) {
        return (m_caller.*TMethod)(message);
    }

protected:
    TCaller &m_caller;
};
```

This allows creating template-generated implementers of the abstract class like this:
(instead of implementing in several different classes and sharing objects between them):

```
struct MyMessage {};

class Logic {
public:
    Logic() :
        m_subscription1(new Invoker<MyMessage, Logic, &Logic::handleSubscription1>(this)),
        m_subscription2(new Invoker<MyMessage, Logic, &Logic::handleSubscription2>(this)) {
    }

    ~Logic() {
        delete m_subscription1;
        delete m_subscription2;
    }

    bool handleSubscription1(const MyMessage &message) {
        // handle message... uses class members
        return true;
    }

    bool handleSubscription2(const MyMessage &message) {
        // handle message... uses class members
        return false;
    }

private:
    Subscription<MyMessage> *m_subscription1;
    Subscription<MyMessage> *m_subscription2;
};
```

---

The thing is, that I would like to allow the user modules (i.e. `Logic` class) an implementation of a `void` handle function as well as a `bool` option.

Now, of course I could create 2 different `Invoker` classes - one implemented just like in the above code, and another taking a 3rd template argument of a void-returning function: `void(TCaller::*TMethod)(const TMessage &)`. In the handle function of the void returning function I would call the pointered function, and return true.

But I was wondering it there's a way to use the same `Invoker` class name so that the user won't have to match the right `Invoker` to the return value of his handle function. Kinda like function overloading - but for template classes.

Of course if I just created two classes with the same name (each taking different return type function template argument), the compiler would scream for redeclaration of template parameter.
So I tried to achieve this with template partial specialization but couldn't figure out a way to define the 3rd template argument without getting a compilation error - I'm not even sure it's the right way to go at it.

When I tried this:

```
template <typename TMessage, typename TCaller, typename TMethod>
class Invoker : public Subscription<TMessage> {
};

template <typename TMessage, typename TCaller, bool(TCaller::*TMethod)(const TMessage &)>
class Invoker<TMessage, TCaller, TMethod> {
public:
    Invoker(TCaller *caller) :
        m_caller(*caller) {
    }

    virtual bool handle(const TMessage &message) {
        return (m_caller.*TMethod)(message);
    }

protected:
    TCaller &m_caller;
};

template <typename TMessage, typename TCaller, void(TCaller::*TMethod)(const TMessage &)>
class Invoker<TMessage, TCaller, TMethod> {
public:
    Invoker(TCaller *caller) :
        m_caller(*caller) {
    }

    virtual bool handle(const TMessage &message) {
        (m_caller.*TMethod)(message);
        return true;
    }

protected:
    TCaller &m_caller;
};
```

I got the following compilation errors on both Invoker implementations:

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for template class Invoker
>   error:   expected a type, got TMethod

And the following compilation errors on the Logic class (for each Invoker):

> In constructor Logic::Logic():
>   error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for template class Invoker
>   error:   expected a type, got &Logic::handleSubscription1
>   error: invalid conversion from Logic* const to int
>   error: cannot convert int* to Subscription* in initialization

What am I doing wrong and is this possible with template partial specialization?
If there's any possible solution I would like to know if it's feasible in c++11 as well as c++98.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but this might work if I read it correctly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38c03828dbdbb63f  (change your logic accordingly). The problem is that you're using a function member pointer, not a type, as your template argument (not even in [temp.param] p4)

Comment: Thanks, This looks pretty good, but the user still has to declare the return type of the function binding he's creating (when defining the `Invoker`) instead of the his pointered function speaking for itself.

Comment: Perhaps this could work then http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0619e964494826db

Comment: does `Invoker::handle` have to be `virtual`?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're aiming at, but I think that my answer is yes. The idea is that potential 'publishers' will hold instances of `Subscription` and will call their `handle` function. This code is a piece of a pub-sub infrastructure.

Comment: being `virtual` rules out the possibility for `Invoker::handle` to be a template

Comment: @MarcoA. the return type is still mentioned in the creation of the `std::function` rather than being automatically deduced from `ClassA::boolFn`'s return type. I liked the former one better. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do

```
template <typename TMethod, TMethod method> class Invoker;

// partial specialization for TMethod = bool(TCaller::*)(const TMessage &)
template <typename TMessage, typename TCaller, bool(TCaller::*method)(const TMessage &)>
class Invoker<bool(TCaller::*)(const TMessage &), method> :
    public Subscription<TMessage>
{
public:
    explicit Invoker(TCaller& caller) : m_caller(caller) {}

    virtual bool handle(const TMessage &message) {
        return (m_caller.*method)(message);
    }
protected:
    TCaller &m_caller;
};

// partial specialization for TMethod = void(TCaller::*)(const TMessage &)
template <typename TMessage, typename TCaller, void(TCaller::*method)(const TMessage &)>
class Invoker<void(TCaller::*)(const TMessage &), method> :
    public Subscription<TMessage>
{
public:
    explicit Invoker(TCaller& caller) : m_caller(*caller) {}

    virtual bool handle(const TMessage &message) {
        (m_caller.*method)(message);
        return true;
    }
protected:
    TCaller &m_caller;
};
```

And usage is something like:

```
class Logic {
public:
    Logic() :
        m_subscription1(std::make_unique<Invoker<decltype(&Logic::handleSubscription1), &Logic::handleSubscription1>>(*this)),
        m_subscription2(std::make_unique<Invoker<decltype(&Logic::handleSubscription2), &Logic::handleSubscription2>>(*this)) {
    }

    bool handleSubscription1(const MyMessage &message) {
        // handle message... uses class members
        return true;
    }

    void handleSubscription2(const MyMessage &message) {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Subscription<MyMessage>> m_subscription1;
    std::unique_ptr<Subscription<MyMessage>> m_subscription2;
};
```